# MySQLi Prepared Statement to compare current time with stored datetime?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have HTML form which I don't want users to be able to use more then once per day.

So far iv'e figured out what I should do but I'm not really sure how.

When a user submits the form I store their "IP" (column ip) aswell as the current time (column submitTime)  and the current time + 23 hours (column releaseTime):

```
$submitDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$currentTime = time();
$releaseTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+23 hour', $currentTime));
```

But what I dont know is how can I proceed? I feel like I'm stuck.

I know I should compare $currentTime with the releaseTime I get from MySQL, but how?

So far I got this code (see the comment lines):

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$stmt1 = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM IPlock WHERE ip=?') or die('Couldn\'t check the IP');
$stmt1->bind_param("s", $ip);
$stmt1->execute();
$stmt1->store_result();
$countRows = $stmt1->num_rows;
$stmt1->close();
if ($countRows > 0) {
/*
 Code to check for how long the IP has existed in MySQL
 If it has existed for more then 23 hours, remove it and proceed.
 else abort (since its blacklisted for another x hours) 
*/
}
```

I know I should not use the IP to identify an user since some users share their IP, but in this case I really have to.

Comment: IP !=user. 1 user can have many IP's and one IP can be thousands of users

Comment: @Dagon I'm aware of that, but in this case I don't have a choice. The users I try to prevent are not registered, and I can't rely on cookies.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Do you want to check the time in the query? In this case why can't you do it the same way as IP? Or you want to compare a value that was fetched from database? Why your question is tagged with prepared-statement then?

Comment: I'm new to Prepared Statements, Yes I would like to get the time in the query and then compare it with the current time and if the current time is greater then the stored time then its a go. I can but I dont know how to compare it with the time, I cant do if ($currentTime > $storedTime) or can I? Im lost

Comment: Yes, you can. This question is irrelevant to prepared statements.

Comment: as its so trivial to work around, it wont actually stop any one who has a reason to post more than once, so therefor is pointless. Its greatest effect will be to annoy people on shared IP's

Comment: @Dagon the website and the form in question is limited to Swedish users and in Sweden almost everyone has their own IP-address, atleast every household.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to check if one has submitted the form in the last 24 hours.

```
SELECT * FROM IPlock WHERE `ip`=? AND `submitTime` > NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR;
```

If IP has not submitted in the past 24 hours, no rows will be returned.

**EDIT:**

In addition to that, there's no need to use PHP `date()` function, you can do your insert like

```
INSERT INTO IPlock (`ip`, `submitTime`) VALUES ('127.0.0.1', NOW());
```

Note that `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` will work just as well.

Comment: Still a small mistake with your `>` which should be `<`.

Comment: No, it is correct. We are looking for a time greater than 24 hours ago. Your example will return any results that are older than 24 hours ago.

Comment: I do not think my solution is the most elegant but it's certainly the easiest. I also think that OP should insert like what I did above.

Comment: Actually @LFlare is correct. He's using the submitTime in hes answer, which means the time should be 24 hours greater then submitTime.

Comment: @DennisEnström Not 24 hours greater, the basic principal is to check to see if any rows has a `submitTime` value **greater** than that of 24 hours ago, or in simple terms, in the last 24 hours.

Comment: @LFlare Yeah but I meant that the current time should be 24 hours greater then the submitTime entry.

Comment: @DennisEnström Regardless, if I've not misunderstood your question, my solution should be correct for your case :)

Comment: I choosed to go with your solution because it was pretty straight forward. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In fact, your problem is different from what you asked.

To compare a datetime value of mysql format you just have to compare it - not a big deal.

The real question is how to get the value for comparison (with your current code you can't) and what to do if you found that the record is outdated.

So, first you need to fetch the datetime value:

```
$stmt1 = $conn->prepare('SELECT releaseTime FROM IPlock WHERE ip=?');//never use die()
$stmt1->bind_param("s", $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$stmt1->execute();
$stmt1->store_result();
$stmt1->bind_result($releaseTime);
$stmt1->fetch();
```

and now you can start checking the date. Note that you don't need the num rows here.

```
if ($releaseTime > date("Y-m-d H:i:s")) {
/*
 Code to check for how long the IP has existed in MySQL
 If it has existed for more then 23 hours, remove it and proceed.
 else abort (since its blacklisted for another x hours) 
*/
}
```